# Job scheduling and packing algorithm

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, scheduling, packing, planning

I was thinking about developing a daily production work plan algorithm for an enterprise. The problem is as  following:

There are various tasks that needs to be completed, each has a deadline, a duration and a set of requirements for resources. It is mandatory that no task is expired, but if that's not possible, we will settle for a plan with earliest completion time.

From there, these tasks will be divided into daily work plan which allows maximum 8 hours of task execution.

I think I'll start from looking at job-shop scheduling algorithms and bin packing algorithm but it that correct? You guys have any idea about how this could be done?

Comment: it's a constraint problem, which is np complete, That means there will be no fast general solver. However that doesn't discount being able to take advantage from certain constraints.

Comment: @ratchetfreak The instance size is effectively fixed because there are only eight working hours in a day, there's presumably an implicit minimum task length and one assumes that the company only takes on work that's approximately possible, so we're probably in a system that isn't massively over-constrained. Given all that (especially the bounded input size), **NP**-completeness probably isn't much of a hindrance.